# laravelのユニットテストを実行してxdebugでカバレッジを取ろうとするとエラーになる

Tags: laravel, phpunit

#### 前提

laravelのユニットテストを実行してxdebugでカバレッジを取ろうとすると下記のようなエラーになりました。対処方法などご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、お教えいただけると助かります。

[image: イメージ説明]

#### 実現したいこと

phpunitでのテスト実行時のカバレッジレポートを出力する。

#### 設定

php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=develop,coverage,debug,gcstats,profile,trace
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = 'host.docker.internal'
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.log = "/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
```

phpunit.xml

```
・・・
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
        <report>
            <html outputDirectory="code-coverage" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="90"/>
        </report>
    </coverage>
・・・
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Laravel Framework 9.23.0

PHP 8.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2022 21:05:41) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.1.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.1.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans

#### 他

同じ質問をterateilでもしています。
https://teratail.com/questions/i9ikbm4r40si6h

Answer (score 0):

xdebug.iniを別途用意していたのを忘れていました。こちらに記載すると反映されました。